# Patching <img> in Angular rapidly

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Currently I have the following problem and would like to know if you have a solution for it or if I am following a completely wrong approach.

I have an HTML page, which in turn has nine `<img>` tags. Over a web socket connection I receive images in Base64 format.

When I get a new image over the connection I overwrite the source of the image.

```
 onMessage(msg: any): void {
    let imgElement = <HTMLImageElement>document.getElementById('foo');
    imgElement.src = msg['image_data'];
  }
```

Unfortunately, the displayed images freeze at some point and the new content is no longer displayed.

I looked at the memory usage in Firefox `about:memory` and see a lot of memory is allocated.

```
Explicit Allocations

1,823.52 MB (100.0%) -- explicit
├──1,713.13 MB (93.95%) ── heap-unclassified
```

Is there a way to release this memory? Because I would argue that this is the reason for the problems

**Addition:**
If I reduce the number of `<img>` tags and web socket connections from nine to e.g. three, the whole thing works without the mentioned problems.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: How do you access img element in your ts file?

Comment: @Chellappanவ Sorry I have forgotton to add it. Its now in the onMessage() function above.

Comment: Does onMessage function getting invoked very frequently?

Comment: @Chellappanவ Yes it gets triggered every time thats not the problem. I even see the <img> source changing in the development console within the browser. But somehow the image is not changing.

Comment: Isn't it a simple change detection problem? Have you tried injecting the ChangeDetectorRef in the component?

Comment: @Sébastien Can you explain what exactly you mean by this? onMessage() is executed every time I receive a new image via the web socket connection.

Comment: @csphmay You are changing the value of a property of the component class. You want the view to reflect the changes everytime. But there may not be an event that automatically triggers Angular's change detection.

Comment: @Sébastien Ah now I get it. Good Point I will try it out later

Comment: @Sébastien I have injected the ChangeDetectorRef and executed changeDetectorRef.detectChanges() after every new socket message. Sadly this is not solving the issue.